# Comparison of methods to create a toolchain: JS modules / loader / build

Tags: javascript, build, module, amd, js-amd

In the process of evaluating the various approaches available to developers to use javascript modules, module loaders and build tools, i'd like some suggestions on what tools you use, and why.

I'm currently after something that is able to:
-encourage modular code
-allow features to be added based on necessity to a given module [think mixins/inheritance]
-produce a BUILD that contains a development release, and at the very minimum a production release with different layers (say, i want a layer [a script] which contains my bootstrap   code, module 1, 2 and 3; and then another layer which contains modules 4,5 and 6. This way I can defer loading of code based on what's actually going on in the application.)
-Work [when built for production] in an extremely low bandwidth scenario, with xfer speeds of 1kbps and high latency (think worst case mobile connection over GPRS to get the picture).

I've seen the following:
Using prototype inheritance, as in:

```
myNS.thing = function(){};
myns.thing.prototype = {
    something: "foo"
}
```

Which can be built by simply taking the contents of this script, and appending it to the next one one wants to include in a production optimized package as a single script. Loaders in this case are simple script tag injections/eval's or similar, based on a known file.

I've also seen other approaches, such as:

```
function(){
    return function(){
        something: "foo"
    }
}();
```

Building this already gets more complex because one has to manipulate the script, removing the wrapping self executing function and combining the return values into one object. I am not aware of an "easy" way to use available build tools. The loader approach works the same as above.

Both of these approaches lack dependencies.

Then we have AMD:

```
define("mymodule", ["dep1"], function(dep1){
    return {something: dep1}
});
```

Some might be nauseated by its indenting, and its "ceremony", but still its quite effective, the google closure compiler knows about it natively, it knows about dependencies, and seems to have widespread adoption across the board. There are a bunch of module loaders available for it (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aqln2akPWiMIdERkY3J2OXdOUVJDTkNSQ2ZsV3hoWVE#gid=2) and quite a few build tools as well.

What other options do you know of, or have you seen used in production?

As said, i'm interested in a combination of code syntax, loader tools and build tools. These three must exist and be working together properly. The rest is an academic excercise i'm not interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use RequireJS, an AMD solution.  If I'm whipping up quick proof-of-concepts I won't bother setting that up, but the most common source/dep-mapping solutions I know of now include:

- RequireJS
- CommonJS
- Google Closure
- YepNope (a conditional loader, can be used in combination with the others)

I have started a boilerplate that uses Require in combination with Backbone to get all the ugly setup code out of the way:

https://github.com/nick-jonas/assemblejs

So you can type `assemble init` to scaffold the basic project and `assemble build` to run the compilers and get a final production-ready build.

Comment: As much as i like requireJS it is HUGE in itself, so i'd tend to use Almond.js instead of it. The main point though is that it still bases off AMD, which many praise (I personally like it too, but my coworkers don't). So to reiterate: Is there anything else besides AMD ?

Comment: Look into these: UglifyJS: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

Google Closure: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3

YUI: http://yuilibrary.com/

Comment: UglifyJS as far as i've understood it is only a minifier, hence it does not really produce a "build" and afaik it knows nothing about dependencies. Or am i wrong?

Comment: I mentioned closure in my answer so i'm aware of that, too. Thanks for the heads up, nonetheless.

Comment: Concerning YUI, i'd prefer to remain framework agnostic. If i were to consider YUI i'd have to consider dojo's build system as well, but i'm not going to, for reasons that mainly have to do with optimizations for extremely low bandwidth scenarios.

Comment: you're correct about Uglify, there are build systems that USE uglify, such as r.js for AMD projects: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in looking at [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) a command line tool with various modules for building javascript projects.  It uses npm for dependencies and it will work with amd modules, but you can just configure it to concatenate the files you need using [grunt-buildconcat](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-buildconcat).